# Displaying multiple related classes in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following model classes called A and B related by a foreign key. So that B has a link back to A with regards to a foreign key. I now want to loop through A, pulling out the potentially numerous B classes. Now here is the twist, what is the smartest way to display these in template?

```
class A(models.Model):
   field1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class B(models.Model):
  aAID = models.ForeignKey(A)
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Right now, getting A is fairly easy as I get the query set, i.e.

```
alla = A.objects.all().order_by("-date")
```

I then can send this via a rendering to a template and loop through alla, but how could I in that template also manage to loop through the B classes found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` class has `b_set` attribute that returns related `B` objects.

You can use this attribute in your templates:

```
{% for a in alla %}
  {{ a }}
  {% for b in a.b_set.all %}
    {{ b }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To quote a great man (and [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)):

> When you define a relationship in a model (i.e., a ForeignKey,
>   OneToOneField, or ManyToManyField), instances of that model will have
>   a convenient API to access the related object(s).
>
> [...]
>
> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the
>   relationship – the link from the related model to the model that
>   defines the relationship. For example, a `Blog` object b has access to a
>   list of all related `Entry` objects via the `entry_set` attribute:
>   **b.entry_set.all()**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the automatically created manager `a.b_set` for this:

```
>>> for a in A.objects.all():
>>>     for b in a.b_set.all():
>>>         print b.field1
```

or in the template:

```
{% for a in alla %}
    {% for b in a.b_set.all %}
        {{ b.field1 }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also have a look at [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Answer (score 2):

You can loop related members just like other attributes in a template, so you can do something like:

```
<table>
{% for a in alla %}  
    {% for b in alla.b_set.all %}
         <tr><td>{{a}}</td><td>{{b}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Its just an example. You do what you want in template